# Async function inside of the React Component returns 'Promise {<pending>}' no matter what I do

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, next.js, spotify

So, I'm trying to run a `asynchronous function` inside of the `functional component` in React (NextJS). But no matter what I do, the function just returns a pending promise like this: `Promise {<pending>}`. I tried fetching the data from a dummy API, and it works as its supposed to.

The thing is that for this particular case, I need to grab the `access_token` from the `getServerSideProps`, which is probably the reason why I am facing these problems (I might be wrong though).

It's worth noting that using a `console.log` inside of the function, instead of the standard `return`, gives the correct result.

```
const checkLoved = async (id: string) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/tracks/contains/?ids=${id}`, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${test.access_token}`,
      },
    });

    const data = await response.json();

    return data[0];
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const session = await getSession(context);

  if (!session) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: '/login',
        permanent: false,
      },
    };
  }

  const {
    token: { accessToken },
  } = session;

  const test = await getAccessToken(accessToken);

  return {
    props: { test, accessToken },
  };
}
```

[Additonal info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73291208/async-function-inside-of-the-react-component-returns-promise-pending-no-ma?noredirect=1#comment129435345_73291208)

What I'm trying to achieve:

```
const Discover: NextPageWithLayout = ({ test }: IDiscover) => {
  const checkLoved = async (id: string) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/tracks/contains/?ids=${id}`, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${test.access_token}`,
        },
      });

      const data = await response.json();

      return data[0];
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  const array = [{ test: 1 }, { test: 2 }];

  return (
    <div>
      {array.map((item) => {
        console.log();

        return <Component test={checkLoved('7jCy1opEtV4a0TnKrtsSdo')}>{item.test}</Component>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Would like to see the further implementation, where you are trying to implement this `checkLoved()`. because these functions looks good to me :)

Comment: For starters. The response is the array, with one boolean (or more if more IDs are provided, but I specify in the function that I want the first element). What I want to do is to use this value throughout the component. I also want to run the function for each mapped component (but obviously I get the usual `Type 'Promise<any>' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'` since it's not resolved).

Comment: Where are you *calling* any of these two functions…?!

Comment: The `checkLoved` function is called inside of the component's render part (JSX). The `getServerSideProps` function is run outside of it as usual.

Comment: I updated the post with the basic idea of what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by creating a custom hook.

```
const useLoved = (id, access_token) => {
  const [loved, setLoved] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const isLoved = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/tracks/contains/?ids=${id}`, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`,
        },
      });
      const data = await response.json();

      setLoved(data[0]);
    };
    isLoved();
  });

  return loved;
};
```

Then you just need to call it:
`const loved = useLoved('7jCy1opEtV4a0TnKrtsSdo', test.access_token);`